# react context with componentdidupdate

Tags: reactjs, lifecycle

I am running a pattern like so, the assumption is that `SearchResultsContainer` is mounted and somewhere a searchbar sets the input.

```
class SearchResults {
   render() {
      return(
        <ResultsContext.Consumer value={input}>
        {input => <SearchResultsContainer input=input}
        </ResultsContext.Consumer>
   )
}

class SearchResultsContainer
  componentDidUpdate() {
      //fetch data based on new input
      if (check if data is the same) {
        this.setState({
          data: fetchedData
        })
      }
  }
}
```

this will invoke a double fetch whenever a new context value has been called, because componentDidUpdate() will fire and set the data. On a new input from the results context, it will invoke `componentDidUpdate()`, fetch, set data, then invoke `componentDidUpdate()`, and fetch, then will check if data is the same and stop the loop.

Is this the right way to be using context?

Comment: Would it be possible to check if the context value has changed instead of data and fetch accordingly?

Comment: I could, that would mean I need to compare the previous context with the current context. And I would have to save the previous context as local state since componentdidupdate doesn't know prevcontext

Answer (score 9):

The solution I used is to transfer the context to the props through a High Order Component.

I have used this very usefull github answer https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12397#issuecomment-374004053

The result looks Like this :
`my-context.js` :

```
import React from "react";

export const MyContext = React.createContext({ foo: 'bar' });

export const withMyContext = Element => {
  return React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return (
      <MyContext.Consumer>
        {context => <Element myContext={context} {...props} ref={ref} />}
      </MyContext.Consumer>
    );
  });
};
```

An other component that consumes the context :

```
import { withMyContext } from "./path/to/my-context";

class MyComponent extends Component {
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const {myContext} = this.props
    if(myContext.foo !== prevProps.myContext.foo){
      this.doSomething()
    }
  }
}
export default withMyContext(MyComponent);
```

There must be a context producer somewhere :

```
<MyContext.Provider value={{ foo: this.state.foo }}>
  <MyComponent />
</MyContext.Provider>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it that **doesn't require passing the context through props** from a parent.

```js
// Context.js

import { createContext } from 'react'

export const Context = createContext({ example: 'context data' })

// This helps keep track of the previous context state
export class OldContext {
    constructor(context) {
        this.currentContext = context
        this.value = {...context}
    }
    update() {
        this.value = {...this.currentContext}
    }
    isOutdated() {
        return JSON.stringify(this.value) !== JSON.stringify(this.currentContext)
    }
}
```

```js
// ContextProvider.js

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Context } from './Context.js'
import { MyComponent } from './MyComponent.js'

export class ContextProvider extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <MyContext.provider>
                {/* No need to pass context into props */}
                <MyComponent />
            </MyContext.provider>
        )
    }
}
```

```js
// MyComponent.js

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Context, OldContext } from './Context.js'

export class MyComponent extends Component {
    static contextType = Context

    componentDidMount() {
        this.oldContext = new OldContext(this.context)
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        // Do all checks before updating the oldContext value
        if (this.context.example !== this.oldContext.value.example) {
            console.log('"example" in context has changed!')
        }

        // Update the oldContext value if the context values have changed
        if (this.oldContext.isOutdated()) {
            this.oldContext.update()
        }
    }

    render(){
        return <p>{this.props.context.example}</p>
    }
}
```

Comment: I see what you did there.  It looks to me that it is a fragile abstraction.  You have to be very sure that this.oldContext.update() is called everywhere/every time its needed or your oldContext can get stale.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass just the value that is changing separately as a prop.

```
<MyContext.Provider value={{ foo: this.state.foo }}>
  <MyComponent propToWatch={this.state.bar}/>
</MyContext.Provider>
```

The extent -> props wrapper seems to a recommended by the react staff. However, they dont seem to address if its an issue to wrap context in a prop for an then consume the context directly from the child of the child, etc.

If you have many of these props you are needing to watch, especially when not just at the ends of branches for the component tree, look at Redux, its more powerful that the built in React.extent.